# How to fetch member list of a MUC room with a member using iOS XMPP Robbie Hanson library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, openfire, muc

I am using the XMPP library of Robby Hanson that is available on git and I am trying to implement MUC or group chat rooms.

I am creating the room using one user, and then try to join, without invite with another user. The problem is, that if I try to connect with another user, not the creator of the room I get the error:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" type="error" id="A7F05488-4A84-4EC0-8A6C-0F1541690534" from="newroom4@conference.administrator" to="newuser229@administrator/abdbd1bc"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"><item affiliation="member"/></query><error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
```

Also I searched the error and I found that error 403 can occur if the user is banned. This is not the case here.
So the error occur when I try to fetch room informations like fetchConfigurationForm or fetchMembersList.

So, here is the code that I am using:

```
- (void)testGroupButtonFunction{
    XMPPRoomMemoryStorage *roomStorage = [[XMPPRoomMemoryStorage alloc] init];
    XMPPJID *roomJID = [XMPPJID jidWithString:@"newRoom4@conference.administrator"];

    xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:roomStorage
                                                 jid:roomJID                                                    
                                    dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppRoom activate:[self appDelegate].xmppStream];
    [xmppRoom addDelegate:self
            delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    [xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:[self appDelegate].xmppStream.myJID.user
                            history:nil
                           password:nil];
}

- (void)handleDidJoinRoom:(XMPPRoom *)room withNickname:(NSString *)nickname{

    NSLog(@"handleDidJoinRoom");

}

- (void)handleIncomingMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message room:(XMPPRoom *)room{

    NSLog(@"Incomming message: %@", message.debugDescription);

}

- (void)handleOutgoingMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message room:(XMPPRoom *)room{

    NSLog(@"Outgoing message: %@", message.debugDescription);

}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items{

    NSLog(@"didFetchMembersList: %@", items.debugDescription);

}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didNotFetchMembersList:(XMPPIQ *)iqError{

    NSLog(@"didNotFetchMembersList error: %@", iqError.debugDescription);

}

- (void)xmppRoomDidCreate:(XMPPRoom *)sender{

    NSLog(@"xmppRoomDidCreate");

}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didConfigure:(XMPPIQ *)iqResult{

    NSLog(@"didConfigure: %@", iqResult.debugDescription);

}

- (void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender {

    NSLog(@"xmppRoomDidJoin");
// I use the same code to create or join a room that's why I commented the next line
//    [xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];
    //Next line generates the error:
    [xmppRoom fetchMembersList];

}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm{

    NSLog(@"didFetchConfigurationForm");

    NSXMLElement *newConfig = [configForm copy];
    NSArray *fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];
    for (NSXMLElement *field in fields)
    {
        NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];
        NSLog(@"didFetchConfigurationForm: %@", var);
        // Make Room Persistent
        if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_persistentroom"]) {
            [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
            [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
        }
        if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_roomdesc"]) {
            [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
            [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"Apple"]];
        }
    }

    [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];

}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didNotConfigure:(XMPPIQ *)iqResult{

    NSLog(@"didNotConfigure: %@",iqResult.debugDescription);

}
```

I use the same code to create or join a room that's why I commented the next line:

`[xmppRoom fetchConfigurationForm];`

Also I want to add that I set:

publicRoom : 1
moderated : 0
membersOnly : 0
canInvite : 1
roomPassword : nil
canRegister : 1
canDiscoverJID : 1
logEnabled : 1

Also if I try to send a message from one device, when I retrieve the message on a second device that is logged with another user(that User is not the creator/admin of the group) I see the incoming message in the console using LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE, but it doesn't call the delegate method.
Any idea why the delegate methods are not called? (and I do add XMPPRoomDelegate  in .h)
Can anyone help me with this errors?
Thank you very much in advance for patience and support!

Answer (score 0):

Is is because it does not follow the XEP0045 instructions. You shoud do a category implementing this method:

```
- (void)joinRoomByContact:(Contact *)contact history:(NSXMLElement *)history
{
    dispatch_block_t block = ^{ @autoreleasepool {

        // Check state and update variables

        // <presence to='darkcave@chat.shakespeare.lit/firstwitch'>
        //   <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
        //     <history/>
        //     <password>passwd</password>
        //   </x>
        // </presence>

        NSXMLElement *x = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"x" xmlns:XMPPMUCNamespace];
        if (history)
        {
            [x addChild:history];
        }

        //XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presenceWithType:nil to:myRoomJID];
        XMPPElement * presence = [[XMPPElement alloc] initWithName:@"presence"];
        [presence addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",roomJID.bare,contact.name]];
        [presence addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:contact.jid];
        [presence addChild:x];


        [xmppStream sendElement:presence];


        state |= (1 << 3);

    }};

    if (dispatch_get_specific(moduleQueueTag))
        block();
    else
        dispatch_async(moduleQueue, block);
}
```

I hope that helps you ;)